# Jquery Slide Toggle Issue in navigation menu

Tags: jquery

I am not familiar with jquery but my clients asking for a Slide Toggle
here the link to the website [Click Here](http://rupajan.com/)
As the you can see the menu is a normal wordpress menu. but once you hover it a slide toggle should take place below the menu except the home, which is working. but sometimes if you click another title in the menu and hover it quickly the slide toggle gets inverse. i.e. the home page gets toggled but all other menu get disabled. my jquery code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#menu-item-1052,#menu-item-1132,#menu-item-814,#menu-item-900,#menu-item-1396').hover(function () {
    $('#space').stop( true, false ).slideToggle('600','linear');
 e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would explicitly call `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`, and bind a `handlerIn` and `handlerOut` to `hover()`:

```
$('#menu-home > li:not(:first-child)').hover(
    function() {
        $('#space').stop( true, false ).slideDown('600','linear');
    },
    function() {
        $('#space').stop( true, false ).slideUp('600','linear');
    }
);
```

Comment: Regarding the downvote, I'd love to improve this answer if something is wrong/incorrect. Care to explain where I went wrong?

Comment: i have implemented it. But there is some serious problems have araised. please see the website

Comment: Can tell in detail how to bind handlers